# Crystal Report Viewer in full screen mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report viewer to display reports on web page. Crystal report viewer covers only 2/3 area of web page on right bottom.

Now client demands for an option to view report in full screen mode. e.g there should be some toggle button etc which will perform full/normal view functionality.

Any help regarding this, will be appreciated.